# How does Quartz monitor the completion of a trigger?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I try to use `TriggerListener` to get `TriggerState` after each execution but it is always Normal, the trigger is released after execution ends.

```
@Override
public void triggerComplete(Trigger trigger, JobExecutionContext context, Trigger.CompletedExecutionInstruction triggerInstructionCode) {
    try {
        Trigger.TriggerState state = context.getScheduler().getTriggerState(trigger.getKey());
        log.info("state:{}", state);
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

How do I know that the trigger has finished executing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so stupid.The time of the next trigger can be obtained through trigger.getNextFireTime(), if there is no next time, it will return null.